# Duvida sobre select em html

Tags: html, html5

é possível digitar em um select como ocorre em programas como access ou base do libre office?

estou montando um formulário onde o campo será inicialmente consultado, mas em caso de necessidade de novas opções de registros queria disponibilizar esta opção para inserção manual. alguém me da uma luz?

Comment: A própria tag _select_ não tem essa opção, você tem que emular algo parecido, usando _input_ e consequentemente, após a inserção de texto, abrir uma _div_ abaixo com o resultado da pesquisa. Seria algo parecido com esse componente do [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete) ??.

Comment: Obrigado Douglas

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Sergio, não consegui entender 100% o que você está tentando fazer, mas uma ideia seria utilizar um botão para o usuário clicar caso ele não ache sua opção, que mostraria um input field, segue um exemplo:

HTML

```
<select name="something" id="">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
</select>

<button>Não achei a opção</button>

<input type="text" placeholder="Digite aqui" />
```

CSS

```
input {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('button').click(function() {
  $('select').fadeOut();
  $('input').fadeIn();
});
```

E aqui caso queira ver ao vivo: http://codepen.io/leofontes/pen/RoGeOr

Espero ter ajudado, é uma opção, com certeza existem inúmeras ideias possíveis.

Comment: Obrigado leofontes,

Comment: @Sergio conseguiu entender o CodePen? Acho que ficou bem claro mas é uma ideia de tratamento.